Pandas display() nice table in AWS Glue Jupyter Notebook
In AWS Glue Jupyter Notebook, I wanted to display() the dataframe in Pandas nice table (HTML) but it only shows the raw text.
Example: In AWS Glue Jupyter Notebook, it only shows the raw text:

Expectation: I want to display it on Pandas nice table (HTML) like this:


I'm working on this same challenge. If I find the solution I will come back and post but hopefully this gets updated by someone else as well. Quite the essential feature of a notebook.

Ditto. Super not user friendly.

I also spent some time trying to crack this. No luck so far. My assumption is that Glue session is streaming the inputs/outputs, so IPython is behaving like it's a terminal, not a notebook.

I have the same problem! Did you try to connect locally to AWS Glue? Is that possible?
